# How to see is a Discord username#tag exists from Dart

Tags: dart, discord

As part of our flutter app -- we ask the user to enter their Discord username#tag .. we do NOT ask them to login to Discord nor is there any need to per se..

However, we do want to check to make sure what they entered is at least valid and defined in Discord.  I am having a hard time finding any method to just validate that the username#tag exists ..

Is there such an API call (I've read the docs a few times but nothing is leaping out at me to see if we can just check if this exists without trying to login)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Flutter? If not, I feel like this is about the Discord API exclusively and the Flutter tag is not needed.

Comment: Maybe better to indicate that it's a Dart question -- I'll change it .. although the answer appears to be "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short said: No, it is not possible.
You need an ID to verify the existence, but it is better to go for Full OAuth so you can verify that your User is not a fraud.

Comment: Alas -- that is the conclusion I have come to as well.  Thanks for verifying.